# Facebook Login with Selenium for C#

Tags: c#, facebook, selenium, fitsharp

I've been playing with the Selenium C# framework and been trying to do a facebook login, but without any luck.

This is what i got so far (based on this post: [Testing a Facebook Connect application using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845614/testing-a-facebook-connect-application-using-selenium/8867886#8867886)). I can't get it to work though.

```
ISelenium sel = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://facebook.com");
public void LoginWithEmailAndPassword(string email, string pass)
{
    sel.Start();
    sel.Open("http://www.facebook.com");
    sel.ClickAt("//img[\\@alt='Facebook']", "User clicks on Facebook Login");
    sel.WaitForPopUp("", "3000");
    sel.SelectPopUp("");
    sel.Type("email", email);
    sel.Type("pass", pass);
    sel.KeyPress("pass", "\\13");
    sel.SelectWindow("null");
}
```

So if someone could provide me with some sample code for how to do this, or guide me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

**Resolved**

By using the record feature of the Firefox Selenium plugin I got the id's and the functions i needed to get it working. The login button seemed to require an XPath definition, which I also got from the Selenium IDE.

```
ISelenium sel = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://facebook.com");
public void LoginWithEmailAndPassword(string email, string pass)
{
    sel.Start();
    sel.Open("/");
    sel.Type("id=email", email);
    sel.Type("id=pass", pass);
    sel.Click("//label[@id='loginbutton']/input");
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Does that even compile?

Comment: It builds. Should have mentioned that I'm testing the dll through the FitNesse framework. It throws an TargetInvocationException Selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]: //img[\@alt='Facebook'].

Comment: When I removed the backslashes from the XPath, it no longer throws an exception. Facebook now loads in a browser window. But it doesn't login and no exceptions or other errors are shown.

Comment: Facebook uses SSL, so you should also change your Uri to https://www.facebook.com  And change the sel.Open to sel.Open("/"). Or use the selenium IDE to record your tests

Comment: Didn't know about the recording feature. That simplified things. Thanks Preben.

Comment: Why are you using Selenium RC as opposed to Selenium WebDriver? Also beware that the IDE can produce quite unmaintainable code.

Comment: Selenium RC was part of a FitNesse tutorial i am following. Unmaintaintable in what aspect? Outdated element id's and such?

Comment: It mainly becomes unmaintainable when you try using complicated CSS and/or XPath selectors because the IDE isn't very clever when it comes to this. For example, it may give you a horrific long XPath solution where a better, more simple, more concise solution can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use WebDriver:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();
driver.GoToUrl("www.facebook.com");

var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));
element.SendKeys(email);
...
element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("submit button id"));
element.Click();
```

This [link](http://blog.stuartfleming.co.uk/selenium/getting-started-with-selenium-2-0-webdriver-and-csharp/) could help you get start.